# Voltage spikes on switch-mode power supply Vout when disconnecting barrel jack

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator, transient

I have a fairly simple circuit that uses a DC/DC converter ([Traco TSR 1-2450E](https://www.tracopower.com/sites/default/files/products/datasheets/tsr1e_datasheet.pdf)) to generate 5V  for my microcontroller board ([D1 mini or similar](https://www.wemos.cc/en/latest/_static/files/sch_d1_mini_v4.0.0.pdf)) from a 12V wall wart. I used the TSR 1-2450E because I don't want to deal with the heat from linear regulators and I don't have the knowledge to design my own switching power supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2JT0O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While testing my circuit, I burned through a few of the microcontroller boards and couldn't figure out why - they were working fine for a while but at some point they drew a lot of current and the LDO on the microcontroller board started to get very hot. So I had a look at the Vout of the DC/DC to see if something fried the LDO, and I found that sometimes, when I disconnect the **barrel jack** (which connects the wall wart to the DC/DC input, not pictured in the schematic), I get these voltage spikes:

[image: 14V spike on Vout for 500us]

I assume that these are killing the LDOs on my microcontroller boards (is this assumption reasonable?). I was under the impression that the TSR 1-2450E would need no additional protection circuitry. Did the DC/DC fail due to some earlier mishandling? Can I add a Zener or TVS to protect against these spikes? I tried to find a TVS that matches my requirements but I'm not sure I understand the parameters. (And I didn't quite manage to simulate them properly in LTspice, at least they didn't do what I expected them to do - clamp above Vbr.)

Edit: I moved my USB scope to a battery powered laptop computer to eliminate the earth connection through the scope to my desktop PC. Also added a channel for V(U1 IN, GND) in yellow, while V(U1 OUT, GND) is green. [image: 14V spike on Vout with Vin]

Comment: What kind of wall wart is it, two prong, three-prong, is it connected to an earthed mains socket or not, is it a linear wall wart or switch mode wall wart? How is your measurement setup, so that we know how you are measuring the spike, so that we are not chasing ghosts. Have you got only the scope connected, how it is connected, and is the scope having a three-prong plug and connected to an earthed mains socket or not?

Comment: The wall wart is labelled WA-18H12, I believe it is switching, and two prong. Scope CH1 is on OUT:GND, CH2 NC, USB powered on a desktop PC (ATX PSU, three prong, earthed).

Comment: Be clear about what devices have failed; is it this: *killing the LDOs* or this: *Did the DC/DC fail*

Comment: How’s your capacitor decoupling and cable length situation?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, sorry. The LDOs are dead, and I can only speculate on the cause. I see 14V spikes out of the DC/DC on the scope, so that might have killed the LDO. I'm not sure where these spikes can come from, so I figured a bad DC/DC might be a root cause - that's why I posted the question.

Comment: Can you confirm if the ``when I disconnect the barrel jack`` refers to a barrel jack at the 12 V _output_ of the wallwart (which is connected to the input of the Traco TSR 1-2450E DC/DC converter)

Comment: Caps: the D1 mini board has a 10uF on its LDO Vin (that's on U2 5V) and on its 3V output. None on the DC/DC. Cable length: wall wart has about 1m, rest is <10cm on a perf board.

Comment: @ChesterGillon exactly

Comment: add a big capacitor to resist changes in voltage, 330-1000uf should just about erase it.

Comment: @dandavis on the input or output of the DC/DC?

Comment: @afflux output (speaking on behalf of dandavis)

Comment: output of dc/dc, input of wemos. on consideration you might not need that much capacitance, it will work for sure, but so could less, experiment. there's no big drawback to having too much (within reason), so long as the DC/DC still starts up; a really really big cap looks like a short and could force it into protection or overheat the diode, but you'll be fine with a few 100 mikes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. What about capacitor material, can I use electrolytics?

Comment: yes, and that's about all you can reasonably get in that capacity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent waveforms.  You have... if not the smoking gun, then at least some "warning shots" fired from it, say?

The MCU board appears to be using a [ME6211C33](https://%20https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2202131900_MICRONE-Nanjing-Micro-One-Elec-ME6211A25M3G-N_C2835782.pdf) regulator, with 6.5V absolute maximum input rating.  Your waveform shows a whopping 13V peak.  It's not clear what is breaking down in that condition; likely the regulator itself breaks down in the 8-10V range, with a zener-like characteristic.  But does that act as a zener to GND or output?  Well, 13V is more than 10V, so it sounds plausible that it's to the output; in which case the output might've even risen a volt or two here.  And the ESP and etc. in turn, might be rated for 3.3V nominal, 3.6 or 4.2V or whatever maximum, and actually break down at say 4.2-5.5V.

How much current, and for how long, any of these parts can withstand breakdown, who knows, but likely not much, and not for long.  Manufacturers rarely say what happens outside of specifications, so we can only guess.  But whatever exactly is happening, specifications definitely aren't being met!

The regulator, however, is well within its voltage limits; the only odd thing being done here, is probably the rapid rise.  The datasheet does not specify input rate of change, so you are not violating any ratings.  I can confidently say the regulator is malfunctioning.

As for why it might be doing that, who knows; I suppose it could be a voltage-mode regulator, i.e. it sets some PWM% into an internal filter inductor, and adjusts the percentage based on output voltage; the feedback circuit cannot respond instantaneously, so a step change in input voltage is immediately reflected as a step change in the output, until the control can react to the change.  What actual type they're using, who knows; this is at least a plausible example.

As for the jack, what's up with that?  Well, consider the metal contacts.  They aren't nearly as flexible as you think they are, on a macroscopic scale.  Electrical contacts are made over length scales of micrometers -- *or less!*  In general, the contact surfaces are rough, bumpy; when placed in contact, they actually touch at only very few sites (surface asperities).  The contact forces might be some ~N total, but at a ~µm contact point, the pressure can exceed the yield strength of the metal!  Sliding them around, smooshes, rounds off and breaks some of those peaks; this can improve the contact area, but it also produces loose material that eventually jams up the contacts, leading to high resistance and intermittent contact (and hence why contact cleaner is such wonderful stuff, washing away the trash and protecting the pure metal surfaces).

There is one more feature missing from that, actually -- vibration.  Things seeming just sitting around, are still alive with motion.  Whether it's vibrations carried through a table, or air currents, or the gradual shifting due to daily temperature fluctuation: the contacts inevitably shift and rock against each other, microscopically, and so contact wear occurs even just in seemingly stationary operation.

Anyway, that's even just a mated contact; what happens when plugging one then?  Well, you can have some guess at this now -- the surfaces will be wildly out of alignment as the connectors are twisted and pulled, metal faces rocking against each other, contact points shifting erratically across the surfaces, and coming loose and slapping back together multiple times; and this can happen over time scales of milliseconds, imperceptible to the human eye but an eternity for electronics -- and well within the oversight of your oscilloscope, as you can see!

You can read the oscillogram as follows:

- 0-7.5 div from the left: contacts are stable, 13V supplied.
- 7.5-8.05 div: contacts opened, capacitors discharging. Regulator within range: output remains steady (green: no change).
- 8.05-8.6 div: contacts mate again, voltage bounces back up on the leading edge (capacitors charging suddenly) then stable.
- 8.6-11.2 div: contacts opened, capacitors discharging.  At 10 div, regulator runs into dropout and output begins discharging.  (Green: drooping.)
- 11.2 div: contacts close again, capacitors charged suddenly.  Regulator apparently didn't reset to a startup condition, or it's effectively stuck at 100%, some kind of recovery effect; in any case, green overshoots wildly.

And then it disconnects finally (or maybe there's more trash offscreen, who cares).

Actually come to think of it, input is 13V and output peak is 13V, that's pretty nasty.

As for mitigation:

Well, I for one will be putting this part on the black list.  This is almost certainly unintended behavior, I don't see how the datasheet would warn of it, and it's clearly destructive.

You can replace it with another type (Recom, Murata, etc. all make modules of similar function and shape) and hope they behave better.

This is a pretty good test actually, I  suppose.  If you replace the MCU board with a resistor load, you can wiggle the connector without worry of frying anything (well, anything *else*).  A more precise and automated method would be to use a power MOSFET and say a 555 timer to pulse the regulator electronically, instead of crunchy mechanical contacts, if you feel interested enough to build a test fixture of sorts.  In any case, measure the waveforms in the same way, and just check that the replacement doesn't produce a huge peak like this.

If the cause is is simply voltage rise, you can add an RC or LC filter to the input, to slow the rate-of-rise.  Using the recommended EMC filter circuit, would likely do this as well (the filter choke has some inductance, which combined with the capacitors, will filter sharp input edges, while being dampened by their ESR).  Something like 1Ω and 100µF would be a good enough start, without costing too much efficiency.  Maybe it needs more filtering than that, I don't know.  Be careful not to add too much inductance, you don't want the filter resonating with the capacitor, rather you want them well damped with their ESRs (specifically, you want \$\frac{L}{C} < {R_\textrm{ESR}}^2\$).  Probably up to 100µH, and one or a couple 100µF electrolytic, would do well enough.  A marginally-rated inductor can be chosen so that saturation and rated current are more than required, but the DCR adds with the capacitor ESR to give a total that meets the above relation.  Or put better: there is some advantage to *not* using an oversized, low-resistance inductor here.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. I already used a ~70Ohms dummy load on the output to replicate most of these voltage spikes. Built the same circuit on a breadboard and used a new DC/DC (just to verify if maybe too much heat during soldering destroyed it) but I see the same effect. I don't see the peak when powering on from 0V though.

Comment: I don't understand "but the DCR adds with the capacitor ESR to give a total that meets the above relation" - do you mean I should satisfy "L/C < (Resr + DCR)^2"?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The Traco TSR 1E Application Notes available at https://www.tracopower.com/int/series/tsr-1e contains the following with a suggested EMI filter:
[image]

While you may not need the full filter if you don't need to test for EMI compliance, the suggested capacitor values could help to remove the spikes.

I'm not sure if when the barrel connector input to the DC/DC converter is removed, it the internal inductor generates a voltage spike which appears at the output due to the input voltage collapsing suddenly, rather than a slower decay when an input capacitor is present.

Comment: The capacitors should help, but it's not really due to a problem of EMI/EMC, rather, it's a problem of the ungrounded two-prong wall-wart SMPS also having an Y capacitor inside it to combat EMI/EMC issues. And that Y capacitor being discharged through the device and PC to earth potential again.

Comment: @Justme: I don't understand how a cap in the SMPS can cause a spike when *disconnecting* the SMPS output barrel jack from the DC/DC input.

Comment: @afflux Just like pushbuttons, the plug connections never simply make or break in ideal fashion and at the same time or always in same order. Real world connector contacts bounce making and breaking, and largest problem is when the plug negative is already disconnected and the plug positive repeatedly breaks and makes connection to the regulator input. Or, were you asking what Y capacitors are and what they do in a SMPS between mains input and isolated output?

Comment: @afflux The updated scope pictures in the question which are monitoring the input and output of the DC/DC convertor show the spike in the 5 V output occurs just after the 12 V input has decayed to 0V and then suddenly returned to 12 V. I think this is the ``Real world connector contacts bounce making and breaking`` which Justme described in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

The switching regulator may need no extra protection, but the pulse may still pass downstream.

This kind of “spike” is common when using wallwarts.

A TVS with a must-work voltage greater than the unloaded wallwart voltage and a clamp voltage less than 36 volts should solve the problem.

Comment: This TVS would be between input and GND of the DC/DC?

Comment: The spike might be common, but also the spike would not exist as such, if the DC plug were connected first and then the adapter plugged to mains. Also it would not exist as such, if the powered device did not have external connections to earthed equipment (such as the PC).

Comment: That is correct @afflux.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from a comment by Justme on another answer, the problem may be that the contacts on the barrel jack are bouncing.  The regulator is then struggling to regulate the voltage when its load bounces rapidly between zero and fully loaded.

Adding a capacitor on the output may help a lot.  You could also consider adding a modest load, permanently wired to the output of the regulator.  Perhaps a "power on" LED.

Comment: @afflux Possibly the question is a but unclear, but from the comments think the sequence is 12 V wallwart -> barrel jack -> (12 V in) Traco TSR 1-2450E DC/DC converter (5 V out) -> D1 mini regulator. When the contacts on the barrel jack _bounce_ it is the input to the DC/DC converter which _bounces_ rather than the output. Therefore, not sure that a modest load on the output of the DC/DC converter will necessarily help. Perhaps the schematic in the question should be edited to clearly label the position of the _barrel jack_ which is subject to be being disconnected.

Comment: @ChesterGillon your understanding is correct - I will update the OP. I don't have the caps at hand right now to check if that resolves the issue. Right now my workaround is to leave the barrel jack connected amd and instead disconnect the wall wart from the wall socket - the LDO stays alive